# Show that $P(m) \ge (m+1)^n$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I need help in this problem.

> **Problem:** Let polynomial $P(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_{n-1} x + 1 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, in which $n \ge 1$ and $a_i \ge 0,    \forall i = 1,\dots,n-1$. Show that $P(m) \ge (m+1)^n$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Just assume $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_{n-1} = 0$

Comment: @Jakobian I didn't understanded your idea.

Comment: Yes, it is not true. It is true that $P(m)\geq m^n+1$

Comment: $P(m)\geq m^n+1$, and $m^n+1$ is a special case

Comment: The problem is show that for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $P(m) = m^n+a_{n-1}m^{m-1}+\ldots+a_1n+1 \geq m^n+1$ for each nonnegative integer $m$ since all coefficients are nonnegative.

In particular, if $a_1=\ldots=a_{n-1}=0$, then $P(m)=m^n+1$. So the inequality (or bound) is tight.

Comment: Could you explain why all coefficients are nonnegative?

Comment: By the hypothesis, just $m$, the variable is nonnegative.

Comment: Also the $a_i$'s are nonnegative by hypothesis.

Comment: But the problem is $P(m) \ge (m+1)^n$.

Comment: Not true, see comment.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false. We could simply set $a_i=0$ for all $i \in \{0,1,2,...,n\}$, and now we'd be claiming:

$$\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \geq (m+1)^n$$

which I think you can figure out is not correct